# Good practice with CSS — One sheet for each page?

Tags: css

The question is simple: it is a good practice we have one "master CSS file" (the same concept of master pages) and, for each page, one specific and unique CSS file?

I ask this because I think that it's useless to have very different code on a page that will not use it — can you all understand me?

Comment: How many pages will you use? Classes can be used across multiple pages if split correctly so you could find yourself repeating code.

Comment: once the css file is loaded, it's then cached. I think it's kinda negligible with css. It would possibly take longer to have to request a different CSS file each time the page changes rather than just load the single cached file.

Comment: The question is a little too subjective. One master CSS provides better caching and less HTTP requests, but as you said, will load unnecessary rules in each page. "Best" practice will vary depending on your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greatest advantage when using one master CSS file than having a master and several specific CSS files is that

1. You save on HTTP request times and resources. If you have several files, you need to call your server a few times and waste on the metadata.
2. Everything is in one place, you get to edit them more easily. CSS becomes more managable for your website.
3. Caching helps greatly.

The redundant / unused style rules in your master file may be too little to matter much.

Comment: "more managable" is subjective, having a CSS file with 5k lines isn't very manageable for many people.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté But CSS is very good in the fact you know exactly what class/id you want to edit, and there should only be one instance of it. So just cntrl + f, instead of changing file then cntrl +F

Comment: Yes @Andy, however if you're not working alone, each edit you make in the "master CSS" will force everyone else from the front-end team to update it before editing and then merging modifications from different members will take more time than writing the CSS itself. Modularization helps speeding up development in that aspect.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté and that's why we have stylesheet languages that compile into one master CSS file

Comment: @mauris In that aspect "one master CSS" does not have anything to do with "more managable".

Comment: The Mauris' vision are pretty smart and convinced me. I will resume all of my CSS into a single file.

Answer (score 2):

From a UI point of view...

Use separate CSS if:

- You have almost independent pages with less common stuff
- You need to reuse specific pages in different projects

Use single CSS if:

- You have lot of common styles

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is best to have as less number of stylesheet (css) and JavaScript files as possible to reduce number of HTTPS requests.

Having one large css file is better then having 5 different files as most likely the css file will be cached in the user's browser after initial request and cached CSS file will be served after first request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is best practice for the following reason:

When the user loads your website they will take the hit of downloading the singel CSS file on first load - thereafter it will be cached by their browser for every page on your site under your main domain. This means no more loading of the CSS file from the server for surfing your site and faster page loads.

If you have separation concerns from a code structure point of view I would encourage you to consider some CSS pre-compilers such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)  that will allow you to structure your code in a nicer way.